# How to signal an Android thread to execute a method?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I want to spawn a thread that sleeps, then executes a method on reception of a signal.  Once the method is complete the thread should go back to sleep, waiting for the next signal.

The incoming signals are frequent enough to where I don't want the overhead of spawning new threads each time a signal comes in. Currently, I am polling for the signal, but I believe there is a better way to do this.

I've seen examples of using Handler and AsyncTask but I'm not quite sure what the best implementation is.  Any suggestions?

```
public ModuleFeedbackTask extends Thread
{
    RadioModule radioModule;
    public ModuleFeedbackTask(RadioModule radioModule)
    {
        this.radioModule = radioModule;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        //Previously just called the function
        //moduleUpdateTask();

        //Currently polling for an update
        //What I want to do is sleep until I get some signal
        while(mState == JOB_STATE_RUNNING)
        {
            //Poll module 
            moduleUpdateTask();

            //Sleep
            sleep(5);
        }
    }

    public moduleUpdateTask()
    {
        //Check if module is ready for processing
        if(radioModule.updateReady)
        {
            radioModule.updateReady = false; //Clear flag
            //do some intensive stuff
        }
    }
}


/**
 * Callback when a radio module reports new data
 * @param m Radio module with new data
 */
@Override
protected void onModuleStatusReport(RadioModule m)
{
    if(mState == JOB_STATE_RUNNING)
    {
        //The below comments spawn a new thread on each feedback... 
        //I want to get around this

        //ModuleFeedbackTask moduleFeedbackTask = new ModuleFeedbackTask(m);
        //moduleFeedbackTask.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY);
        //moduleFeedbackTask.setName("ModFbTask");
        //moduleFeedbackTask.start();

        super.onModuleStatusReport(m);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are numerous ways to tackle this problem, but I'll suggest using a `BlockingQueue` shared between the worker thread and any other threads that can signal it to perform its task.  The worker's task is set up in a loop, at the top of which it attempts to `take()` an object from the queue.  This will block until some other thread enqueues an object, which constitutes the signal.

Some of the advantages of this approach include:

- you can easily and naturally queue up multiple signals at once, so that if the worker is actually working when a signal is posted, that signal is not lost;
- you can convey information to the worker via the enqueued object, such as task parameters or a signal to quit instead of performing any task;
- you have a built-in option for using a timeout on receiving signals; and
- all `BlockingQueue` implementations are thread-safe, so you do not need to worry about implementing your own synchronization.

*Example*:

```
public OnDemandTask implements Runnable {
    private final BlockingQueue<?> signalQueue;

    public FeedbackTask(BlockingQueue<?> signalQueue) {
        this.signalQueue = signalQueue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                // blocks until an object becomes available from the queue
                // may throw InterruptedException
                signalQueue.take();

                performTask();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            // we've broken out of the loop; nothing further to do
        }
    }

    private performTask() {
        // ...
    }
}
```